# Jenkins stage maven install is getting skipped

Tags: maven, jenkins

When building a project in jenkins, the maven install step is getting skipped with the following message:

```
Stage "Maven Install" skipped due to when conditional
```

Jenkins file content are below:

```
@Library('scheduling-pipeline') _
standardPipeline {
  skip_jacoco_report = true
  agent = "AssemblyBuild"
  use_private_maven_repo = true
  skip_pom_check = true
}
```

I don't think this should happen. Any ideas as to where I should look for the cause?

Comment: Could you please provide your Jenkinsfile or the configuration of your job?

Comment: added the Jenkins file

Comment: That's not all. I suppose the rest is in your global lib which has conditional..